# no php artisan commands are working after new migration

Tags: laravel, migration

I am new to laravel .
Following tutorial videos on laracast,i made a new migration (cmd command) like following

```
php artisan make:migration delete_title_from_posts_table
```

which gave me the message

```
Created Migration: 2020_02_05_185721_delete_title_from_posts_table
```

after that no php artisian command is working in cmd.

Any command i run gives me the following error

```
In Container.php line 805:

  Target class [db] does not exist.


In Container.php line 803:

  Class db does not exist
```

what would be causing this?
my laravel app version=6.2 and php version=7.3.5 on Win10 64-bit.

similar questions i already viewed,not working for me

[artisan-commands-not-working-after-composer-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974116/laravel-5-1-php-artisan-commands-not-working-after-composer-update)

[in-container-php-line-805-target-class-db-does-not-exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59455066/in-container-php-line-805-target-class-db-does-not-exist/59455185#59455185)

Comment: What if run -> composer dump-autoload <- and then -> composer update <-

Comment: already tried this that gives the same error but with additional response ----Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1----

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a facade, add this to the top of the class to make it work:

```
use DB;
```

Or use full namespace:

```
$tables = \DB::table...
```

Comment: in which file? also i am using a eloquent model not a query builder

Comment: this error will be shown when you use the DB library but not declare on the top

Comment: You Must Try composer dump-autoload maybe its cache issue

Comment: already tried that from similar answers i mentioned in the post

Answer (score 0):

run these commands steps by step:

- `composer dump-autoload` clean up all compiled files and their paths
- `composer update --no-scripts` Skips execution of scripts defined in `composer.json`
- `composer update` update your project's dependencies

Comment: i already tried this solution,this gives me the same error but with the additional message ''> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
    Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1